# How can I get a debug version of my iPhone app onto my iPhone?

Tags: iphone, testing

I'm trying to get just ONE copy of my application on my real iPhone to test it. How can I do this without going through the appstore?

Comment: Have you paid the iPhone developer fee?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, go to the [program portal](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/manage/overview/index.action).  From here, you should read through the [program portal user guide](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/download.action?path=/iphone/iphone_developer_program_user_guide/iphone_developer_program_user_guide__standard_program_v2.5__final.pdf) and you can also launch the assistant to help you through the steps of configuring your project and workstation.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have all your certs in order all you have to do is add the said phone to your list of development iPhones on the developer portal. Once you do that you will need to generate the provision file and assign it to the iPhone in the xcode organizer.  For more information just reference the iPhone development documentation Apple provides on deploying your games onto development iPhones.